# Parameter 'user' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts

Tags: angular, firebase, google-authentication

I always getting this Error trying to set up an Google Authentication with firebase.

> Parameter 'user' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)

I searched everywhere but i cant figure out how to fix it :/

The code:`enter code here`

```
user$: Observable<User | null | undefined>;    
async googleSignin() {
        const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        const credential = await this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(provider);
        return this.updateUserData(credential.user);
      }
    
    
      private updateUserData(user) {    //This user causes the Error
        // Sets user data to firestore on login
        const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<User> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);
    
        const data = { 
          uid: user.uid, 
          email: user.email, 
          displayName: user.displayName, 
          photoURL: user.photoURL
          } 
    
        return userRef.set(data, { merge: true })
    
      }
```

Can someone pls help :D

The documentation for this code: https://fireship.io/lessons/angularfire-google-oauth/

Comment: Give that parameter an explicit type?

Answer (score 1):

If you have set `"noImplicitAny": true,` on your `tsconfig.json`, typescript wouldn't allow you to write expressions or definitions without a type.

Here, the argument `user` doesn't have a type and its type can't be inferred from another expression.

For example when you right

```
const username = "Tom";
```

the username's type is inferred from "Tom" which is `string`.

So you should either specify `any` for the type of user:

```
private updateUserData(user: any) { 
  ....
}
```

or use your specific `User` type if you have any in your codes.

```
import { User } from 'path/to/types/definitions'

private updateUserData(user: User) { 
  ....
}
```

Comment: Please mark it as "Answer" if it was what you were looking for.